# Can't display MBProgressHUD progress animation properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, mbprogresshud

I would like to display a hud while the content is loading (and show the progress), but unfortunately it doesn't work properly. The hud appears on the screen when `statusUpdate` is `0.100000`, but the loading bar doesn't moves until `statusUpdate` is not `1.000000` and the page loading finished. (After the view loaded sucessfully it animates from 0-100%.)

What am I doing wrong?

```
// ViewDidLoad    
[self.webView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"estimatedProgress" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
 
    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
    [self.view addSubview:HUD];
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeDeterminateHorizontalBar;
    HUD.delegate = self;
    HUD.labelText = @"Uploading";
    
    [HUD show:YES];
    [self hud:self.webView.estimatedProgress];
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"estimatedProgress"] && object == self.webView) {
        
  //   [self.progressView setAlpha:1.0f];

 //    [self.progressView setProgress:self.webView.estimatedProgress animated:YES];

        
        
        NSLog(@"%f", self.webView.estimatedProgress);

   }
    else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
        

          NSLog(@"%f", self.webView.estimatedProgress);
    }
}

- (void) hud: (double)statusUpdate  {
    
    NSLog(@"STATUS %f", statusUpdate);
    
    int myInt = (int)statusUpdate;
    
    HUD.progress = (float)myInt;
    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, the problem is on `- (void) hud: (double)statusUpdate`

For some reason you're casting the value (`statusUpdate` which is a `double`) to `int` and then again to a `float`, which means that `0.x` values become `0.0` and `1.x` values become `1.0` (that's why these are the only values that HUD is getting - since your range is 0.0/1.0)

A simple fix would be something like this:

```
- (void) hud: (double)statusUpdate  {

    NSLog(@"STATUS %f", statusUpdate);

    HUD.progress = statusUpdate;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is how i used it before:

```
UIViewController *vc = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:vc.view animated:YES];
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;
    hud.progress = 0;
    hud.labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"Loading...", nil);

[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
        CGFloat progressValue = ((CGFloat)totalBytesRead/(CGFloat)totalBytesExpectedToRead);
        MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD HUDForView:vc.view];
        hud.progress = progressValue;
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create something like animation using CADisplayLink. It will update your HUD.

```
@interface ViewController () {
    CADisplayLink *displayLink;
}
- (void)displayLinkMethod {    
    displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(animationMethod)];
        [displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}
```